# Error in the output of my java program

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to do a java program but I am having a problem with the output.

Here is the error I get when I input the information.

```
Enter social security number:12345678
```

Enter salary3000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:12345666
Enter salary2122
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:900000000
Enter salary3000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:-1

Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ':'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2547)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2533)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Salaries.output(Salaries.java:57)
    at Salaries.main(Salaries.java:19)

And here is my code so far..

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Salaries {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[] ssNumbers = new int [10];
    double[] salaries = new double [10];
    double[] nSalaries = new double [10];
    int c;

    c = inputData (ssNumbers, salaries);
    raise (salaries, c);
    output (ssNumbers, salaries, nSalaries);
}

public static int inputData (int[]ssn, double[]sals){

    int c = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int ssNum;

    System.out.print("Enter social security number:");
    ssNum = input.nextInt();

    while (ssNum != -1) //using while loop.
    {
        ssn[c] =  ssNum;

        System.out.print("Enter salary");
        sals[c] = input.nextDouble();
        c++;

        System.out.print("Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:");
        ssNum = input.nextInt(); 
    }
        return c;

}
public static void raise (double[] salaries, int c)

{
    double[] salaryraise = new double [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++ )
    salaryraise[i] = salaries[i]*.02;

}
public static void output (int[] ssNumbers, double[] salaries, double[] nSalary )
{
    System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%:\n", "Social Security Number", "Salaries", "Salary After Raise");
    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++)

        System.out.printf("%d %.2f %.2f", ssNumbers[i], salaries[i], nSalary[i]);

    return;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "%:" in this line you'll wanna remove. (because it's not a valid specifier)

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%:\n", "Social Security Number", "Salaries", "Salary After Raise");
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
    System.out.printf("the salary after raise is %f\n:", salaryraise);
```

To:

```
    System.out.println("the salary after raise is: " + salaryraise);
```

Comment: my apology. this line should not be there at the first place.
I edited my code.
Thnx

Comment: Yes. but a different one. See my edited post to see the error I am getting now.

Comment: It seems this error is in the output method and also is because of your print statements.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix it? I am just so confused

Answer (score 0):

The % character at the end of format make the error.
Should delete it lis below:

```
  System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%:\n",
>>System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s:\n",
```